# When i try to flip images with`transform: rotateY(60deg);` it will not flip 60deg

Tags: css, image, flip

When i try to flip images with`transform: rotateY(60deg);` it will not flip 60deg but 0deg. I am using Google Chrome so is this a bug or...?

I has set the styles on a image with the class `ig`. Does it work with an image with a class?

Thanks, Pascal Gerrist

Comment: You have to add a vendor prefix in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome is a webkit browser. So you have to user a prefix for CSS3 codes.

And your code will be :

```
-webkit-transform: rotateY(60deg);
```

---

### Demo : [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9PwCh/)